# After 5 minutes desktop boot, some program(s) starts on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-services

The system is `Windows 7`, 32 bits. I have started only `Thunderbird`, `Skype`, `7 Sticky Notes` and `Look'n'Stop` firewall.

5 minutes after system boot and full desktop load, I get a busy cursor, the windows which is in focus goes out of focus and the hard drive starts making noises (working). In Task Manager I can see some processes are getting started and stopped very fast. I'm assuming this is a windows task.

**How can I find out what program started and it's path?**

Comment: Did you check the superfetch service? It is a pre-loader, although should not have the symptoms the same as you described them.

Comment: SuperFetch was started. I did disabled it for now to see if it's going to behave the same on the next days.

Comment: Apparently superfetch was the problem. Since I disabled it, I no longer have that behaviour. Thanks Psycogeek!

Answer (score 0):

You can type `msconfig` in run command

Browse `startup` tab

You can see list of things which gets `started at process`

Comment: I already told what programs are starting. I use `emsisoft emergency kit` to disable startup programs. It has a more advanced version of `msconfig`.

Comment: @machineaddict i am not aware of it,thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a more advanced version of task manager: [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). It will show you all the details you need:

[image]

It has several features that you'll find usefull:

- It displays in a tree the approximate order in which processes execute each other (you'll know, which process launches your evil process)
- When process closes, it is still displayed for several seconds as "deceased", so you'll have some time to look closer.
- The data displayed on each process is, well... extensive at least.

You may also use [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) which will show you all the apps that are set to start automatically in all the various places application may use in Windows OS

[image]

These are free tools, part of [Windows SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals) suite.